# Implementing copied and pasted code/text detection?

Tags: java, javascript, python, algorithm

I've a bunch of legacy javascript files looking really similar. I'd like to implement a copied/pasted code detection tool, but I was unable to find a description of an algorithm...
I'm already using sonar with the javascript plugin to detect this kind of code, but I'd like to have a finer-grained control over the detection...

Is there any "standard" algorithm for this problem ?
Is there any library to perform this analysis (python or java...)?

thanks.

Comment: You may want to look here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5748/are-there-tools-to-determine-code-similarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look to [CloneDigger](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/), it is designed to detect clones in python or java code, but the algorithm is [described here](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/duplicate_code_detection_bulychev_minea.pdf).